# unable to parse urdf file

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

The question is extremely simple:
when I type the line (quoted):

```
<origin xyz="${reflect*camera_offset_x} 0 0" rpy="0 ${camera_offset_p} 0" />
```

the urdf is parsed, everything is great, I can visualize in rviz and when I type:

```
<origin xyz="${reflect*camera_offset_x} 0 0" rpy="0 ${reflect*camera_offset_p} 0" />
```

it doesn't work anymore..

Here, reflect can be 1 or -1 and it seems to by no problem for entering negative values for the angle offsets...

So where the hell could the problem come from?

Thanks for your time.
Yours,
Lucian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36901/unable-to-parse-urdf-file/) by [Lucian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1876/lucian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I figured this one out:

camera_offset_p was declared as:

and if I declare it as:

which is equivalent, it works again.

Maybe someone could explain me why then?

---

Originally posted by [Lucian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1876/lucian/) with karma: 16 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-20**:
There is no pre-defined constant M_PI in xacro as far as I know.

**Comment by [Lucian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1876/lucian/) on 2012-06-21**:
I already predefined M_PI as 3.1415